# Bind Observable collection to ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, observablecollection

With Xamarin and Visual Studio 2017, I get an abstract `The application is in break mode` message when debugging.

When using `try-catch`, nothing is catched.

I already debugged that the returned TimeLog collection is not empty.
`from`&`to` are given by `DateTime` values.

TimeLogs is an observable colletion applied with `ItemsSource` to the `ListView`.

```
private ObservableCollection<ExtendedTimeLog> TimeLogs;
```

In the ctor of the code behind file:

```
TimeLogs = new ObservableCollection<ExtendedTimeLog>();
TimeLogView.ItemsSource = TimeLogs;
```

After having a not empty logs collection the process crashes.

```
private async Task RefreshTimeLogs(long from, long to)
{
         TimeLogs.Clear();
         var logs = await DB.GetExtendedTimeLogs(from, to);

         foreach (var element in logs)
             TimeLogs.Add(element);
}
```

The refresh method is called by a datepicker{To,From}_DateSelected method.

```
  <DatePicker x:Name="datepickerFrom" Grid.Row="0" DateSelected="datepickerFrom_DateSelected"></DatePicker>
```

XAML:

```
<ListView  x:Name="TimeLogView" Grid.Row="2">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <TextCell Text="{Binding From}" />
                                    <TextCell Text="{Binding To}"   />
                                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Note}" />

                                </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

When having an empty collection (in the for loop) and the observable collection is not changed, then an app crash does not occur.

What must be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, that works fine.
The 3 `TextCell` entries are replaced by `Label`.